# Unify Grub Customiser across multiple partitions

Tags: boot, grub, linux-mint

The 500Gb SSD boot drive of my Linux Mint PC has several partitions...

> **nvme0n1p1** (537Mb) efi boot partition
> **nvme0n1p2** (50Gb) current live "House PC" copy of Mint 21
> **nvme0n1p3** (24Gb) copy of Mint 20 only used to run backups
> **nvme0n1p4** (20Gb) previous "House PC" (originally Mint 20) installation no longer used
> **nvme0n1p5** (417Gb) "user data drive" where I keep my "documents" (movies, music, etc.)

When I break into the Linux boot process with DownArrow, my choices are...

> Linux Mint 21.1 Vera (21.1) (on /dev/nvme0n1p2)
> Ubuntu
> Linux Mint 21.1 (Vera (21.1) (on /dev/nvme0n1p4)
> UEFI Firmware Settings

...where the first option (the default) just boots my live system

option 2 boots me into the "backup" system which I only use to run [fsarchiver](https://www.fsarchiver.org/) (to create a backup of the live system on nvme0n1p2.

option 3 doesn't work properly - if I select that, it just boots into my live system on nvme0n1p2 anyway. I think that's because something went wrong when I tried to upgrade to Mint 21 "in situ" from my original Mint 20 system. I don't really care about it, but it's there at the moment.

Note that I created the "cut down" list of options myself, by installing and running [Grub Customizer](https://itsfoss.com/install-grub-customizer-ubuntu/) after booting into the Backup system on nvme0n1p3. I remember I deleted all the "Advanced" options - I might have changed the order as well, but that's not important. I might as well have deleted option 4 (UEFI settings), but obviously I didn't bother to do that.

My problem is the copy of Grub Customizer on my live system is working on a *different* set of boot configuration files, so any changes I make there aren't reflected in the real boot process.

I asked chatgpt how to fix this, and as usual it was supremely confident. First, it had me run these two commands...

> **sudo mkdir /mnt/boot**
> **sudo mount /dev/nvme0n1p1 /mnt/boot**

...then it told me to create symlinks using...

> **sudo ln -s /mnt/boot/EFI/ubuntu /mnt/nvme0n1p3/EFI/ubuntu** (I think I *need* this or similar)
> **sudo ln -s /mnt/boot/EFI/ubuntu /mnt/nvme0n1p5/EFI/ubuntu** (probably not interested anyway)

...after which I just need to execute **sudo update-grub**

I'm not prepared to blindly execute the first **sudo ln** command, because even I can see it won't work. Partly because I know the relevant EFI folders are lower case, but mainly because even lower case **ls /mnt/nvme0n1p3/efi/ubuntu** doesn't give a directory listing, so it's probably not the right path.

I'm not interested in whatever's gone wrong with partitions 4 and 5. I could happily delete both of them. But I'm inclined to suspect chatgpt is right when it tells me the problem can be solved using symlinks (which I don't really understand).

All I want is for Grub Customizer to update the same boot options regardless of which partition I boot from. Is there any chance anyone could just tell me straight off *exactly* what those two paths passed to the **ln** command should be?

Comment: Though I have used Grub Customizer, realize there are some serious issues: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1404445/grub-customizer-missing-from-ubuntu-22-04 . Also, recent Linux updates have undone some of the changes made through that tool, such as specifying font or attributes. Use with caution!